# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException In WCF Webservice

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-mac

I am creating WCF web service. So i got an example in Github. [Project Example](https://github.com/oscarkuo/wcf-samples/tree/master/FilelessActivation)
 I am able to compile the project. But i am getting System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException error.

My URL is: http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/HelloService.svc/

My IDE: Visual Studio 2019 MAC

[image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="v1/HelloService.svc"
         service="FilelessActivation.Services.HelloServiceImpl"
         factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services>
  <service name="FilelessActivation.Services.HelloServiceImpl">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingNamespace="http://oscarkuo.com/v1/hello" 
              contract="FilelessActivation.Services.IHelloService" />
  </service>  
</services> 
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that we have to enable Windows feature to support SVC extension in IIS. Subsequently, we could have this service working.
[image]
Besides, please note, In the WCF project, No need `SVC` file doesn’t represent that the relative address in the ServiceActivations doesn’t contain `SVC` extension.
**Result.**
[image]
Related links.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuration-based-activation-in-iis-and-was
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.